# Batch file to find an integer in file

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have a text file which will have a string CommSessionMgr and then space and then number(like below)

It will have only one line of these 
CommSessionMgr  0
CommSessionMgr  1
CommSessionMgr  2

Example: test.txt

---

srvrmgr:sibsrvmqint2> list comp CommSessionMgr show CC_ALIAS,CP_NUM_RUN_TASKS

CC_ALIAS        CP_NUM_RUN_

---

CommSessionMgr  0

1 row returned.

---

from the above example, i want to find out what is the value( 0 in the above example) we have next to CommSessionMgr string. This is has to done through batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('type test.txt ^| find "CommSessionMgr"') do set "integer=%%i"
echo %integer%
endlocal
pause
```